# How can I avoid repeating the same query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have a query in below. I use this query in multiple place but this queries  almost same. Only where conditions change.

This is my query

```
select
c.first_name,
c.middle_name,
c.last_name,
c.birth_day,
c.birth_month,
c.birth_year,
c.marital_status,
c.education_status,
c.departmant,
c.create_date,
c.create_user,
c.modify_date,
c.modify_user
from customer c 
where c.place='london' and c.create_date>getdate()-100
```

I use same query in multiple place but only where conditions change. So I repeat below part everywhere.

```
select
c.first_name,
c.middle_name,
c.last_name,
c.birth_day,
c.birth_month,
c.birth_year,
c.marital_status,
c.education_status,
c.departmant,
c.create_date,
c.create_user,
c.modify_date,
c.modify_user
from customer c
```

How can I avoid this. How do I prevent repetition and increase query performance.

Comment: _I use same query in multiple place_ Where? In what context? Add more details.  And SO id designed for one question per post. Your goal of avoiding extra work is not related to "increase query performance".

Comment: The above just looks like it's a basic `SELECT` against a table; nothing more. Though you *could* use something a `VIEW` I really don't see the benefit here. If it were something more complex, sure, but you're not really saving anything in the above

Comment: First, use parameters instead of constants. Maybe that's enough to change the conditions, can't tell without having more info.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to reuse the base SELECT, eg

```
create view vCustomer
as
select
c.first_name,
c.middle_name,
c.last_name,
c.birth_day,
c.birth_month,
c.birth_year,
c.marital_status,
c.education_status,
c.departmant,
c.create_date,
c.create_user,
c.modify_date,
c.modify_user
from customer c
```

Then you can run queries like:

```
select * 
from vCustomer c 
where c.place='london' 
  and c.create_date>getdate()-100
```

Comment: Then, the OP can just run `select * from vCustomer c where c.place='london' and c.create_date>getdate()-100`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an *inline* Table Valued Function. This acts like a parameterized view (and performs just as well, if not better)

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION GetCustomer
(
  @place varchar(100),
  @fromCreateDate datetim
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

select
  c.first_name,
  c.middle_name,
  c.last_name,
  c.birth_day,
  c.birth_month,
  c.birth_year,
  c.marital_status,
  c.education_status,
  c.departmant,
  c.create_date,
  c.create_user,
  c.modify_date,
  c.modify_user
from customer c 
where c.place = @place
  and c.create_date > @fromCreateDate;

GO
```

You would use it like this

```
SELECT *
FROM GetCustomer( 'london', DATEADD(day, -100, getdate()) ) c
```